# Webdriver object gets overwritten when tests are run in parallel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm writing Java based selenium-web-driver tests to run a parallel cross browser test using testng .
I have set the tests to run parallel on my xml file.The file looks like this :

```html
 <suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >    
 <test name="ChromeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />               
   <classes>
      <class name="test.login"/>
      <class name="test.main"/>
      <class name="test.logout"/> 
   </classes>  
 </test>

<test name="FirefoxTest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />              
   <classes>
      <class name="test.login"/>
      <class name="test.main"/>
      <class name="test.logout"/> 
   </classes>  
 </test>
```

But when i run test, both browser instances gets opened (Chrome opens first and starts execution and after a delay Firefox is opened).
In that case , the driver object gets overwritten by Firefox driver and chrome stops execution.Tests continue execution on Firefox and 
gets completed successfully.

The structure of the project is like this :

- Created a **driverbase.class** to load driver corresponding to browser which has my **@Beforesuite**.
- Crteated individual classes for  pages.(Eg: **login.class , main.class etc**) which has only **@Test** method and have extended driverbase class to get driver.

Test are run suceessfully when  i set parallel to none on xml file

```
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="none" >
```

How can i overcome this issue? How to run tests in parallel without this issue?

The driverbase class is like this :

```html
public class driverbase {
 
   private String baseUrl;
   private String nodeUrl;
   private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
   private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
   
 public static WebDriver driver = null;
           
    /**
   
    * This function will execute before each Test tag in testng.xml

    * @param browser

    * @throws Exception

    */
          
 @BeforeSuite

 @Parameters("browser")

   public WebDriver setup(String browser) throws Exception{
  
       //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
   
       if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        
        System.out.println("Browser  : "+browser);
             
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
      profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    
      //create firefox instance
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
       
       }
       
       //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'

       else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

        System.out.println("Browser  : "+browser);
               
     //set path to chromedriver.exe You may need to download it from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");

           ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           options.addArguments("--test-type");
         
     //create chrome instance
            
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          
       }
     
        else{

           //If no browser passed throw exception
         
         System.out.println("Browser  is incorrect");

           throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");

        }
   
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return driver;
   
 }
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: can you post driverbase.java?

Comment: Added driverbase code snippet

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Answer (score 1):

1. `@BeforeSuite` methods are not supposed to return something. => replace by `void`
2. Your testng has 2 differents tests, but `@BeforeSuite` will always be run once by suite what your comment shows you doesn't expect it. => replace by `@BeforeTest`
3. When you run in //, 2 threads are settings the driver value (one with firefox, one with chrome) which explains your problem.

You can try something like:

```
public class driverbase {

  private String baseUrl;
  private String nodeUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();   
  public WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  @Parameters("browser")
  public void setup(String browser) throws Exception {
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
          FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
          profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
          driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
      } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("--test-type");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      } else {
          throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
      }

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

You should have a look on http://fluentlenium.org/ too.

Comment: I tried that.But no success.I am able to run tests with parallel = false.On that case both tests run successfully.

Comment: Attributes are not thread safe in my example. You can wrap them into ThreadLocal or use a @Factory instead of the before class method.

Comment: Found a solution using HashMap .Now i am able to run tests in parallel.

Comment: Can you post a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To sure that same instance of webdriver won't be assigned to multiple tests. The method where driver instances are being created should be **synchronized**. This should solve the issue.

```
public synchronized void setup(String browser) throws Exception {
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
          FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
          profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
          driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
      } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("--test-type");
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      } else {
          throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
      }

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```